# line spacing in tikzposter

Tags: tikz-pgf, line-spacing, tikzposter

The line spacing in blocks of the tikzposter seem to depend on the number of paragraphs or the presence of images included by the use `\includegraphics`.
For example in the poster example distributed with the tikzposter package, the line spacing is different in two paragraphs of the right block titled "Columns". How could I define a uniform line spacing in all the poster blocks including the title?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually you could just have posted the first two words of the title and not bothered with the example:-)

Bad linespacing in TeX is almost always due to changing the font size but not including the end of paragraph in the same scope, which results in the new size text being set to the original baseline.

In the cited example you need

```
\block[c]{Columns}{
     The page can be divided for some segment of the poster into columns of vertically aligned blocks by using the environment \cmd{ columns}.  Within this environment, a column is begun with the command, for instance, \\
     \vspace{1em}
     \cmd{\bs column\{}0.40\cmd{\}}\\
     \vspace{1em}
     for a column of blocks center aligned along a vertical line with default width of $40\%$ of the available width.
     Following this, additional blocks are created which will be aligned into this column until a new column is called
     or the environment is ended.  The current column can be used for reference by the variable \cmd{\bs colwidth}.%
\par%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<this par (or a blank line) needed here
}
```

Probably the definition of `\block`  ought to provide an implicit end of paragraph, but clearly it doesn't so you need to add it explictly.